# Horizontal and vertical line on mouse move

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

How do I implement the horizontal and vertical dotted line on mouse move as shown in the link?

I'm thinking of implementing that to my chart but there isn't much information online except a few using LineBuilder(which seems to be deprecated).

I'm using JavaFX 8.

Can anyone show me an example please. TIA

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByzL6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will make an attempt, but it is not integrated with whichever chart you are using.

```
public class CrossLine extends StackPane {
    private Line vertical;
    private Line horizontal;

    public CrossLine() {
        this.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        vertical = new Line();
        horizontal = new Line();

        vertical.getStrokeDashArray().add(2d);
        horizontal.getStrokeDashArray().add(2d);

        vertical.setStartX(0);
        vertical.setStartY(0);
        vertical.setEndX(0);
        vertical.endYProperty().bind(this.heightProperty());

        horizontal.setStartX(0);
        horizontal.setStartY(0);
        horizontal.endXProperty().bind(this.widthProperty());
        horizontal.setEndY(0);

        getChildren().addAll(vertical, horizontal);

        this.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED, event -> {
            double x = event.getX();
            double y = event.getY();

            vertical.setTranslateX(x);
            horizontal.setTranslateY(y);
        });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
StackPane container = new StackPane();
container.getChildren().addAll(chart, new CrossLine());
```

There will probably be some latency too, it could probably be solved if the event could be moved into some `layout` method override.

Comment: Thank you, integrated with what i'm doing and it works. Like you mentioned it does has some latency but it's fine for my use case.